# How to merge google chrome user of home and work

Tags: google-chrome

I have the following configuration:

- Google chrome at home
- Google chrome at work

I need to have the two chromes merged in one account, using differents users.

I want to be able to Sync my google account in others computers, and have the two users, work and home.

Anyone have some idea of what's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[According to Google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/63304?hl=en), it's currently **not** possible to merge two different accounts. It's possible, however, to [move data](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/58582) out of certain products, namely:

- AdWords
- Blogger
- Bookmarks (Export and import)
- Contacts (Export and import)
- FeedBurner
- Finance: Export and Import
- iGoogle (To transfer data, create your own backup and restore it to
  the new account through XML)
- Picasa Web Albums
- Places (bulk upload)
- Reader
- YouTube

Unfortunately, Chrome isn't currently on the list of the supported products. More information about merging accounts [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1109839?hl=en).

However, there's another way to achieve this, albeit using a third-party extension. [Xmarks](https://www.xmarks.com/) allows you to sync your bookmarks to all of your devices that have Xmarks installed. It also allows you to set up [Profiles](https://www.xmarks.com/about/features/sync_profiles), which gives you the ability to separate bookmarks according to your needs.

**Assign bookmarks to sync profiles**

[image: Assign bookmarks to sync profiles]

**Assign sync profiles to computers**

[image: Assign sync profiles to computers]

[This page](https://www.xmarks.com/about/features/sync_profiles) walks you through the process of setting this up.